# Creating a menu bar icon without having a visible running application associated with it

Tags: java, macos, notification-area

I want to create a menu bar icon that is not associated with a running application. Just like dropbox's menu bar icon doesn't appear as an open application, but only on the menu bar.

What I got so far is the code for adding the menu bar icon:

```
package tray;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import logging.Logger;

public class TrayObject {
    private TrayIcon trayIcon;

    public TrayObject() {
        if(SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            try {
                trayIcon = new TrayIcon(
                            ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Add.png")), 
                            "CodeLibrary");
                SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.log(this, "IOException");
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                Logger.log(this, "AWTException");
            }   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrayObject to = new TrayObject();
    }
}
```

When I run the application the menu bar icon is showing as it should.

[image: Image of my system tray]

However, the problem is that I don't want the application 'TrayObject' to have a menu bar nor be visible when tabbing among applications. I want the menu bar icon to be there without being associated with the running application 'TrayObject'. Is it possible to do this in Java, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the application up as a `.app` bundle using [appbundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler) then you can add the `LSUIElement` property in `Info.plist` to suppress the dock icon and menu bar.

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

(see [this apple.stackexchange question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68915/hide-a-running-app-from-dock) for an example)